# C++, process stops in Console Application

Tags: c++, console-application, codeblocks

Hi I am using Codeblocks and a problem occurs when I start this program:

```
int number_STABLE= 2;
int number_VARIABLE;
int numberof_STEPS = 0;

void Check() {
    number_VARIABLE=number_STABLE;
    while (number_VARIABLE!=1) {
            if (number_VARIABLE%2!=0) {
                number_VARIABLE=(number_VARIABLE*3)+1;
            } else {
                number_VARIABLE=number_VARIABLE/2;
              }
            numberof_STEPS++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout<<" - STARTED - "<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    while (numberof_STEPS!=555) {
        numberof_STEPS=0;

        cout<<"Stable: "<<number_STABLE<<endl;
        cout<<endl;

        Check();
        number_STABLE++;
        number_VARIABLE=0;


        cout<<"Steps: "<<numberof_STEPS<<endl;
        cout<<endl;

    }
    cout<<"Number of steps: "<<numberof_STEPS<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Last number: "<<number_STABLE-1;

    return 0;
}
```

It runs for approximately two minutes then it stops. When closing the console app window this is the error message displayed in the Build log:

> Process terminated with status -1073741510 (1 minute(s), 54 second(s))

Could someone explain why this happens and/or how can I prevent it?

Comment: A good way to go through this would be using a Debugger. It will then show you the stack trace of what happened and where the program crashed.

Comment: What do you want to do with this line? `while (numberof_STEPS!=555)` It appears you want to find a number for which the Collatz Conjecture does not hold (yet) after 555 steps. If so, you program might be running  a really long time and eventually create a stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you want to find a number that requires exactly 555 steps? If there doesn't exist one within valid range of `int`, your variable will overflow at some point and restart at negative values (actually undefined behaviour) and at some point reach start value again -> so cycling virtually forever...

Comment: @infinitezero Yeah, exactly that, I was curious how long can I run it.

Comment: @infinitezero Not a stackoverflow - integer overflow...

Comment: @Aconcagua right, I was somehow thinking in recursions.

Comment: @Aconcagua Largest number that reaches is around 113500.

Comment: Do you just want to find *any* number or the smallest one for which this condition applies? If it is *any*, you might simply calculate 2^255... Not with ordinary `int`, neither with `unsigned long long`, as all of these would overflow. So you'd need some big integer library.

Comment: @Aconcagua The smallest.

Comment: Brute force might not be the ideal way to go anyway. I'd try the inverse: Start duplicating the number until a value less by one is dividable by 3; if so then decrement and divide. Repeat this until you have reached 555 steps. If that really produces the smallest number I cannot guarantee, though, would have to be proven mathematically before...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you! I  saw an interesting challenge in it, I am a beginner and wanted to practice a little bit, it seemed like a great opportunity.

Comment: Forget about my algorithm, it already fails for 12 steps, finding 48 where 9 would have been a better solution :(

Comment: Accepted (?) answer hints to global variables – you indeed should minimize their usage to the absolutely necessary minimum – where you wouldn't need any at all in given case! `unsigned int steps(unsigned int n)` would be a far better signature (unsigned: negative are meangingless for -1 * 3 + 1 = -2, resulting in an endless loop for never reaching 1),

Comment: and you would accept the next number to check as parameter, replacing `number_variable`, while `number_steps` would be a local variable to `steps` (former `check`) function and being returned. `number_stable` can then be local to the while loop and is passed as parameter to the function.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you for absolute everything! If I could ask you a favor, would you write a summary from your comments in an answer so that I can close this thread?

Answer (score -2):

First of all, these two lines are nonsense:

```
while (numberof_STEPS!=555) {
    numberof_STEPS=0;
```

This loop will never exit.

Second: Do not use global variables as loop variables. Automatic variables are much faster because they will be put into a register. Incrementing the variable outside the function containing the loop makes it all worse because the program becomes totally incomprehensible.

Third: Your technical problem presumably is an integer overflow. The Collatz sequence rapidly reaches the 2^31 limit. Try this one:

```
int i;
i = 2147483647;
cout << i << endl;
i++;
cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate _"these two lines are nonsense"_? Why is it not possible that `Check` sets `numberof_STEPS` to 555? Global variables aren't the best approach but probably don't cause the problem. There is no fixed 2^32 limit in C++ for `int`. The size of `int` is compiler specific.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, although half of what you are writing is pretty much nonsense to me because I am just curious beginner , but I hope that some day I become a bit more advanced and I can fully understand what you are saying.

Comment: *'Nonsense'*? Not completely: We increment the start value for `check` function and the latter one does *multiple* steps before exiting – and if there's indeed a number that requires 555 steps to terminate then the loop *would* stop. Agree on usage of global variables, though and possible overflow problem.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Global variables are declared outside of int main , right?

Comment: Yes, global variables are declared outside.